# How to copy a monochrome bitmap in resources to disk as monochrome bmp in c#

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

Using WinForm, I have a small bmp file in the resources which is just black and white so two colour, saved as Lion.bmp. I need it just two colour as bmp. When the user clicks on a button a dialog comes up asking them where they want to save this. I want to then copy the resource to that space but save it as two colour bmp just as the original in resources. I have managed to save it as all manner of other files and even a 32 bit bitmap but not a two colour bitmap.

First I thought I would just copy byte for byte but found that was not possible with my knowledge. I could probably do it if I knew how.

Next I thought I would just create a new bitmap and save it

```
 new Bitmap(Resources.Lion).Save(dialog.SelectedPath + "\\lion.bmp");
```

This compiled and I was happy till I realised I was saving a PNG file called .bmp. Next I find that I can add an Image format so I try

```
new Bitmap(Resources.Lion).Save(dialog.SelectedPath + "\\lion.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Again it compiles and saves a file but even though the resource is monochrome it saves it now a 32bit colour depth and not 2. I next try to just write it out as a stream of bytes which was my original plan

```
File.WriteAllBytes((dialog.SelectedPath + "\\lion.bmp"), Resources.Lion);
```

That does not compile as it says Resources.Lion is not a byte[] but I think it must be as it is in resources. Next I find in Bitmap I can have

```
Encoder.ColourDepth, 2
```

I think this would work but I cannot work out how to use that as ever time I try it will not compile.

```
new Bitmap(Resources.Lion).Save(dialog.SelectedPath + "\\lion.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp, (Encoder.ColorDepth,2));
```

I guess I need to ask those wiser than me what the syntax may be to get this to work so that I can copy the monochrome bitmap from resources to monochrome bitmap on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end a colleague came up with the suggestion of cloning the resource "Lion" that I wanted.This has worked. The code I used is below:

```
Resources.Lion.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, Resources.Lion.Width, Resources.Lion.Height),System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed).Save(dialog.SelectedPath + "\\lion.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: Not a bad solution, but be careful with it: it works for 1bpp since black and white are the default Windows palette colours on 1bpp. But on other indexed formats like 4bpp (16 colour) and 8bpp (256 colour), it will not do an accurate conversion to an optimal palette; it will just match the pixels on the image to the Windows default colour palettes for these colour depths.